# pdf sdk for Mac osx

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, quartz-graphics

I am writing an application for Mac OSX and I need to manipulate pdf files. I only need to split existing pdf files (extract certain pages) and combine existing pdf files. I found PDFtk Server but it only supports Mac OS X 10.8 and older.

Any recommendations ? Does the built-in PDFKit library cover my use cases?

Comment: To simply split and combine PDFs, you could just use the in-built Preview.app.  See https://www.howtogeek.com/201519/use-your-mac’s-preview-app-to-merge-split-mark-up-and-sign-pdfs/

Comment: @DDP: I want to do it programmatically.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Did you tried to install PDFtk Server in your macOS? I know your version is more recent than 10.8, but maybe it works.

Comment: What's wrong with built-in PDFKit?

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's own PDFKit Programming Guide

"PDF Kit is extremely flexible, allowing you as much or as little control over PDF documents as you like. Whether you simply want to display a PDF document in a help window or you want to create a full-featured PDF editor, PDF Kit can simplify your task."

It's only a couple of pages long, although the pages are a bit long themselves, but best option would be for you to check the actual guide, link below.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Intro/PDFKit_Prog_Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001863-CH203-SW1